# PCB key contact

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, power-electronics, pcb-fabrication, synthesizer

[image]

Hi! anyone knows how to design a pcb like this in the photo with eagle? Someone has a guide to do it? I don't know how the resistor should be placed.

It is basically a pcb for a synth, the key contact pcb

Comment: What is under the gray parts? What "resistor" are you talking about? Where's the schematic for the board? That all seems like pretty critical information.

Comment: This is a rather open ended question.

Comment: Find a manufacturer with engineering services that does this sort of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a silicone molding placed over a PCB. The PCB will have either gold-plating or a carbon printing where the key switches bridge electrodes.

You can find design guides for this sort of thing, but if you have a source for the silicone keyboard molding, they would be the ones to ask.

[Here](https://www.siliconedynamics.net/wp-content/uploads/design_guide/9271Silicone-Dynamics-Keypad-Design-Guide.pdf) is one such design guide.

The exact tool (eg. Eagle) you use to implement the design is not a big issue, the main issue is designing the patterns themselves.

Comment: thank you! @spehro the problem is that i don't have the schematics for the pcb. the contact rubber are not a big deal. i can't figure out how to draw the pcb itself

Comment: maybe could be this the schematics? https://i.imgur.com/U3e5HFJ.gif

Comment: Maybe.. hard to see if there are diodes on those boards, but in any case you're going to have a bad time of it if you don't know what EXACT circuit you want to implement.

Comment: here are back and front of the pcb https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Key-Contact-Circuit-Board-For-KORG-Poly-61-61M-DW-6000-Parts-/202391347660?oid=202345564799

Comment: Yeah, it would be pretty easy to copy that given a sample, so not sure what the question is. Note the holes that are punched (or drilled) out to isolated the traces that need to be connected together for plating.

Comment: that I don't know where to start for copy it

Comment: Get the exact physical dimensions of the PCB, mounting holes, locations of contacts, connector. Make footprints and schematic symbols for the diode, the connector and a contact. Redraw the schematic in the program you are using. Create the PCB and route the connections just as in the sample. Create the Gerber and drill files. Send them off to the manufacturer. When they come back, profit!